# How to get path of media files in android

Tags: android, file

I want paths of files shared through share intent from any app. I do get path of files like zip, apk, pdf, etc. with code `ShareCompat.IntentReader.from(this).getStream().getPath();`.

But but I don't get path for image, video and audio files I get `content://media/external/video/media/40666`, How to get real path of files of this type?

Comment: That is a nice content scheme uri. Use it!

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the path, you can use the following code

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
    document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":")+1);
    cursor.close();

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,null
            , MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
    cursor.close();

    return path;
}
```

It basically uses he ContentResolver to get the data of the file.

You can change the query parameters to get what you want.

Or you can use

```
getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)
```

If you want the entire file